# Use environment based appSettings in .NET on same windows server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I have two environments UAT and Production which are on the same windows server but different folders. We have appSettings.json and appsettings.development.json.

I would like UAT to use appsettings.development.json and production to use appsettings.json

We have Github workflows for CI/CD. We have dev.yml and prod.yml. Here is the file

```
name: Build and Publish to Server

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop


jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checking username
        run: whoami
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Build Dotnet application
        run: dotnet build
      - name: Release Dotnet application
        run: |
         stop-webapppool DevAPI
         stop-iissite -Name DevAPI-Confirm: $false
         dotnet publish DevAPI.App.Api -c Release --output C:\backend\dev
      - name: Run Dotnet application 
        run: | 
         start-webapppool DevAPI
         start-iissite -Name DevApi
```

I have added the following code in startup.cs as well

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Now I cannot just add environment variable on the windows server because UAT and production are using the same server. Also, we are not using dotnet run command but publishing and running it in IIS. How can I configure different appsettings.json based on the environment

Answer (score -1):

In the startup.cs file, you can according to the environment name to add the related appSetting file. Code like this:

```
    public Startup(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        var envname = "";
        //according to the Environment name to select the appsettings file.
        if(env.EnvironmentName =="UAT")
        {
            envname="appsettings.development.json";
        }
        else if(env.EnvironmentName =="Production")
        {
            envname="appsettings.json";
        } 

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile(envname, optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Then, you can set the environment variable using the following methods:

1. Use web.config.

   To set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable with web.config, see the Set environment variables section of [web.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-environment-variables).
2. IIS deployments.

   Include the  property in the publish profile (.pubxml) or project file. This approach sets the environment in web.config when the project is published:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

   To set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable for an app running in an isolated Application Pool (supported on IIS 10.0 or later), see the AppCmd.exe command section of Environment Variables . When the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable is set for an app pool, its value overrides a setting at the system level.

   When hosting an app in IIS and adding or changing the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable, use one of the following approaches to have the new value picked up by apps:

   Execute `net stop was /y` followed by `net start w3svc` from a command prompt.
   Restart the server.
3. Set environment variable globally.

   Open the Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings and add or edit the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value.

More detail information, see [Set the environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#windows---set-environment-variable-for-a-process)

Comment: This is not working. I have tried everything but it still takes all the values from appsettings.json instead of development. I even tried adding ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in control panel -> System.